# MAMP goest to 100% CPU on Magento installation

Tags: magento, mamp

I'm trying to move my Magento development to MAMP and getting problem with 100% usage on httpd both for new installations (after Create Admin Account) page and for existing stores moved from test server.
I'm using MAMP Pro 2.0.1 with PHP 5.3.6

Also I've changed following settings and enabled xdebug:
max_execution_time = 1800
memory_limit = 128M

If anyone faced similar problem or have any suggestion please share

Comment: Switched to PHP 5.2.17 and all works now

Comment: FYI, this is likely what the issue is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400154/iconv-strlen-function-causing-execution-timeout-running-on-mamp

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the insight, should probably wait for the MAMP update or switch to ports. You can post your reply as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed in MAMP 2.0.2 http://blog-en.mamp.info/2011/08/mamp-pro-2-0-1-released.html